Khronos VK-GL-CTS base for Android CTS =(e.g. 14_r3_11432042). How to check deqp base of Android CTS?
What is Khronos VK-GL-CTS base (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS)
for Vulkan Android_CTS? How to check deqp base of Android CTS ?
I want to be able to map:
Android 14_r3_11432042 -> Vulkan-CTS-1.3.x.x
Android 14_r4_xxxxxxxx -> Vulkan-CTS-1.3.x.x
In https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts/cts-14-release-notes:
"Updated dEQP branch for Android 14 CTS to use vulkan-cts-1.3.5 (instead of 1.3.1)".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm testing Android and Linux OS. I want to have mapping what tests are present on both (what is the common part).  The best would be to know the base of Android CTS tests (14_r3 in my case). I've checked in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/deqp/+/refs/tags/android-cts-14.0_r3 and: Android CTS 14.0 Release 3 (11432042) was released on 13 Feb'24
but latest commits from Khronos repo is from 31Aug'23

93763ac0 Fix invalid memory index used in AHB import tests

